how to change get request in cashfree payment gatway to post?

I want to make cashfree payment gatway dynamic for that I want to change get method of cashfree to post method, as by get method I am unable to make dynamic filed of user and product .

I want to get current user and product and add it in payment method intead of static data.
Cashfree.XClientId = process.env.CASH_API_ID;
Cashfree.XClientSecret = process.env.CASH_SECRET;
Cashfree.XEnvironment = Cashfree.Environment.SANDBOX;

function generateOrderId() {
  const uniqueId = crypto.randomBytes(16).toString("hex");
  const hash = crypto.createHash("sha256");
  hash.update(uniqueId);
  const orderId = hash.digest("hex");
  return orderId.substr(0, 12);
}
export const paymentinitiate = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    console.log();
    var request = {
      order_amount: 1,
      order_currency: "INR",
      order_id: await generateOrderId(),
      customer_details: {
        customer_id: "walterwNrcMi",
        customer_phone: "9999999999",
      },
      order_meta: {
        return_url:
          "https://www.cashfree.com/devstudio/preview/pg/web/checkout?order_id={order_id}",
      },
    };


this is the code in server I am using for making payment. I want to make it  dynamically.
I am unable to find its solution ???

I am using the same code as provided by cashfree payment gatway. in tha static data is showing but I want to change it dynamically but method is get ,, in get method cart  cant be sent.

I want to send dynamic data in request of cashfree server side request in payment initiate, which is now static.

Cashfree lets you send dynamic data. This is how you would modify the above code. The key is to use order_tags. More about it here
import { Cashfree } from "cashfree-pg"; 

Cashfree.XClientId = process.env.CASH_API_ID;
Cashfree.XClientSecret = process.env.CASH_SECRET;
Cashfree.XEnvironment = Cashfree.Environment.SANDBOX;

var request = {
    "order_amount": 1.00,
    "order_currency": "INR",
    "order_id": "order_44594806",
    "customer_details": {
        "customer_id": "walterwNrcMi",
        "customer_phone": "8474090589"
    },
    "order_meta": {
        "return_url": "https://www.cashfree.com/devstudio/preview/pg/web/checkout?order_id={order_id}"
    },
    "order_tags": {
        "name": "Developer",
        "company": "Cashfree"
    }
};

Cashfree.PGCreateOrder("2023-08-01", request).then((response) => {
    console.log('Order created successfully:',response.data);
}).catch((error) => {
    console.error('Error:', error.response.data.message);
});

